# when need to do this in c++; if(x = 0) {}

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I noticed sometimes developers do these in their project;

```
while(int x = 0) {//run code}
```

```
int y = 0;
if (y = someFunction())
{//run code}
```

I want ask;

1. why c++ allow to do these in loops like while,(maybe for as well?) and if-else statements, what is the usage?
2. when someone should do this in his project?
3. and when conditions like these give result true?

Comment: I don't remember to see it used in `while` and your `while(int x = 0)` will execute the loop `0` times, hence unlikely that you saw it like this in code. Do you have a more "real" example? If you really saw `while(int x=0)` then that could be a typo in the code you were reading

Comment: If they had written `while(int x = 0) {` then they are pulling your leg. Actually this is one reason why I prefer `while(!x)`, rather than an explicit comparison to zero. The yoda type expressions `while (0 == x)` make me feel like I've just drunk two bottles of a cheap Merlot.

Comment: Voted for reopening. It is not an duplicate of the proposed duplicate, or at least not an exact duplicate. In this question the assignment is an assignment to zero.

Comment: @user1810087: You have an answer prepared? If so I'll reopen.

Comment: I'm happy to reopen as well, if you don't think it's a duplicate. I certainly wouldn't mind seeing an explanation of `while(int x = 0) {`.

Comment: @Bathsheba You can always ping the user who dupe-hammers a post if you disagree with the closure. They are accountable for voting to close, and in most cases will be happy to reevaluate.

Comment: @cigien: Ping!!!!!

Comment: I think most people with the hammer will at least read the comments, and be most curious to see the answer.

Comment: @Batsheba you are an easy guest then. Showing you `while(0 != x)` for dinner is even cheaper than the merlot

Comment: fwiw, I agree that the dupe is not the right one, but then still the question needs clarification. "I have seen sometimes" should come with a real example.... or maybe not, the question can be answered as it stands now

Comment: Note that the 2 snippets are not equivalent. The first one evaluates to `false`, but the second one depends on `someFunction`. Could you also add the source where you saw this? The surrounding context might help understand the use case.

Comment: I've actually seen once `while(int x = 0) {` in code made by a college. It was a very odd way used for debugging purpose. He would literally change the value `0` to some number to stress another function. He also used some defines like `#if 0` which is not uncommon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232737/if-0-as-a-define . But this is not a definitive answer, to the question...

Comment: @user1810087 That's a preprocessor conditional. OP is asking about a run-time conditional. I think those are different things.

Comment: @user1810087 I have to resort to such madness when coding Java sometimes, because our settings don't allow me to have unreachable code, maybe thats similar

Comment: @user1810087: I prefer a `goto` for that purpose as I have a static analyser set up to fail a build of any code containing a `goto`. If you leave an `#if 0` or `while(int x = 0)` by accident all hell could be let loose.

Comment: @cigien you are right, and I don't want to give the impression to have the answer for this or that it is my preferred way do go. I'm only trying to say I witnessed such code myself, but had the luck to ask the programmer for the reason. :-)

Comment: @user1810087 I understand, it certainly sounds like fun :) I'm not entirely sure that such a discussion is suitable though. It seems to invite opinions, rather than facts.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the usage?

Declaration inside `if`/`for`/`while` allows to reduce scope of the variable.

so, instead of

```
int y = somevalue();
if (y) {// y != 0
// ...
}
// y still usable :/
```

or

```
{ // extra block :/
    int y = somevalue();
    if (y) {// y != 0
        // ...
    }
}
// y no longer usable :)
```

you might directly do:

```
if (int y = somevalue()) // y != 0
    // ...
}
// y no longer usable :)
```

with syntax which might indeed surprise.

For more controversial:

```
int y;
// ...
if (y = somevalue()) // y != 0
    // ...
}
// y still usable :)
```

it is allowed as that assignation is an expression convertible to bool (value of `y = x` is `y` (which has been assigned to `x`)).

it is more controversial as error prone as unclear if `=` or `==` is expected.
some convention use extra parents to more clearly express assignation

```
if ((y = somevalue())) // really = intended, not ==
    // ...
}
```

> when someone should do this in his project?

For existing projects, try to use existing convention.

For new project, you have to do the trade of:

scope versus syntax not shared with other language which might be surprising

> and when conditions like these give result true?

when given expression convert to true, so non zero integral, non null pointer.

c++17 introduces another syntax to allow to split declaration and condition for `if`/`while`. (`for` already allow that split)

```
if (int y = somevalue(); y != 42) // y != 42
    // ...
}
// y no longer usable :)
```